# Return an entire table according to value selected by user in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a cell configured with a drop-down list, from which the user would pick an option. Depending on what the user selects, I want a table to be displayed in a given part of the Excel file.

This table has three columns and some 15 rows, with the corresponding headers.

I tried with `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX`, but they are not working, as they only returns one value.

Let's suppose the drop-down cell is in tab "Data", cell A1. The table is in tab "Table", from cells A1 to C16. I'd like the returned data to be displayed in any part of tab "Data".

Any advice will help.

Comment: Please post the data, so we can have a better idea of what you are trying to do

Comment: A1 contains the drop-down list, with the following options: Peter, Mark, John. So, let's suppose that `A1 = Peter`. According to this choice, I'd like a table located in another tab to be returned in B3:E18, for example. It's difficult to exemplify how the table looks here, but it's an common table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a combination of the `Offset`, `Indirect`, `Row` and `Column` functions as well as the `Vlookup`, with the lookup listing the location of the first cell in the table for each value in A1.  For example, the Vlookup looks for the value in A1 in the columns G:H, and returns the text description of where that table starts.  The Indirect changes the text string to a reference to that location, and then the Offset returns the value a certain number of rows or columns away.  The formula entered where you want the data table to be displayed is:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($A$1,$G:$H,2,FALSE)),ROW()-3,COLUMN()-2)
```

I think this may be clearer by looking at the pictures below.

[image: Values with first selection in Drop Down]

[image: Values with the second selection in Drop Down]

[image: Formula]

[image: Table sheet]